# Is $\mathbb{S}^2$ self-similar?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A topological space $X$ is *self-similar* if there is a proper subspace $Y \subsetneq X$ such that $Y \cong X$ (homeomorphic).

> Is $\mathbb{S}^2$ self-similar?

I guess no, but, how can I prove this?

Comment: Do you know about homotopy?

Comment: If $\mathbb{S}^2$were self-similar, then it could be embedded inside the plane (that's because $\mathbb{S}^2$ without a point is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^2$). Can you prove that this is impossible (it is a consequence of Borsuk-Ulam)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f:\mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow  Y$ is a homeomorphism where $Y \subsetneq \mathbb{S}^2$. Pick $p \in \mathbb{S}^2 \setminus Y$. Then $\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{p\} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ via stereographic projection (from $p$), say $h$.

But then $h \circ f: \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ would be 1-1, while Borsuk Ulam says that $p \in \mathbb{S}^2$ exists with $h \circ f(p) = h \circ f(-p)$, contradiction.